# SendMessage() find window rectangle

Tags: c++, msdn, sendmessage

I am making a program that can get information from another program window. Specifically I want to know the coordinates of the second programs parent window... so I thought that I could use the function SendMessage(hWnd, Msg, WParam, LParam) to get the rectangle coordinates somehow... but I have been looking for an appropriate message to do so from the following msdn site and couldn't find it:

[**MSDN: About Messages and Message Queues**´/ System-Defined Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_defined)

If anyone can tell me what the right message (second variable for the SendMessage() function) would be, that would be awesome!! If there is a better way of getting the windows coordinates, please let me know!!! I am open to all solutions!

Comment: Uhh...To send the message to the window you have to have it's HWND, right? If that's the case, what's wrong with using GetWindowRect?

Comment: nothing is wrong, I don't know that function. I'll look it up in msdn Thanx! if anyone else has other methods and/or tips, please let me know!

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, use a combination of GetWindowRect and MapWindowPoints. MapWindowPoints allows you to convert to and from different coordinate spaces( ie, convert a window position that is relative to it's parent to screen coordinates. )